# Can't upload image to site on IE8: System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to upload am image to an IIS 6 (Windows 2003 Server) site using the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Empresas empresas)
    {
        Empresas e = db.Empresas.Where(em => em.Id == empresas.Id).First();
        e.NombreEmpresa = empresas.NombreEmpresa;
        HttpPostedFileBase archivoBanner = Request.Files["Banner"];
        HttpPostedFileBase archivoLogo = Request.Files["Logo"];

        string directorioUpload = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + e.CodigoEmpresa);
        if (!Directory.Exists(directorioUpload))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directorioUpload);
        }

        if (archivoBanner != null)
        {
            if (archivoBanner.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileUpload = Path.Combine(directorioUpload, archivoBanner.FileName);
                archivoBanner.SaveAs(fileUpload);
                e.Banner = archivoBanner.FileName;
            }
        }

        if (archivoLogo != null)
        {
            if (archivoLogo.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileUpload = Path.Combine(directorioUpload, archivoLogo.FileName);
                archivoLogo.SaveAs(fileUpload);
                e.Logo = archivoLogo.FileName;
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(e);
    }
```

If I load it from my PC (Windows 8, IE10, Chrome 29) or from the server using Chrome, it has no issues. If I load it from the server, using IE8 It throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException on "archivoBanner.SaveAs(fileUpload);", saying that the application can't read the source image:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Acceso denegado
>   a la ruta de acceso 'C:\Documents and Settings\user\My
>   Documents\Imagenes\banner.png'.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso
>   'C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Imagenes\banner.png'.] 
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   +12898791    System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share,
>   Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath) +2481
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +229    System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode) +106    System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String
>   filename) +295
>   SistemaSolicitudes.Controllers.EmpresasController.Edit(Empresas
>   empresas) in D:...\Controllers\EmpresasController.cs:73
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +127
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +248
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33()
>   +125    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49()
>   +452    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass37.b*_36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass2a.b*_20()
>   +31    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +230
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +20    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +20
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +20
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +469    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375

I've tryed changing permissions on the destination folder, but as I said, there's no error writing the file, but reading it. So, I've tryed to change the file permissions, whit same result.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you try uploading the file from a folder outside the user folder? For instance, from C:\

Comment: Yes, the result was the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in the following line:

```
var fileUpload = Path.Combine(directorioUpload, archivoBanner.FileName);
```

If `archivoBanner.FileName` contains an absolute path, then Path.Combine will return that absolute path and ignore the `directorioUpload` parameter.

You could try something like:

```
var fileUpload = Path.Combine(
            directorioUpload, 
            Path.GetFileName(archivoBanner.FileName)
            );
```

From your description of the problem, I would suspect that archivoBanner.FileName contains an absolute path in the case that fails, and a relative path or filename only in the cases that succeed.  You can easily verify this.

> That's not the reason. archivoBanner.Filename contains only the filename, not its path in the disk.

The error message suggests your code is trying and failing to access `C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Imagenes\banner.png`.  And this looks suspiciously like the path to the file being uploaded.

> Trying from my desktop with a file called "banner.png", the values are...

That's consistent with your statement that you had no issues when uploading from your PC (which I assume is what you mean by "your desktop").  Try tracing the uploaded filename when uploading from the server with IE8.

The [documentation for HttpPostedFile.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename.aspx) says that it is "the fully qualified name of the file on the client".  I suspect most browsers don't send the fully qualified name, especially for a remote client, for security reasons.  But your description of the problem suggests that IE8 does so when it's a local client.

Comment: That's not the reason. archivoBanner.Filename contains only the filename, not its path in the disk. Trying from my desktop with a file called "banner.png", the values are: directorioUpload = "D:\\Desarrollo\\...\\Images\\117", archivoBanner.FileName = "banner.png", fileUpload = "D:\\Desarrollo\\...\\Images\\117\\banner.png"

Comment: Thank you, Joe. You were right. Internet explorer 8 was sending the complete path instead of the filename. Your sugestion helped me solve the conflict.

Comment: +1, i never thought such a small mistake took me a full day to fix.. Thanks to you !

Answer (score 0):

Well my first thought is that maybe you should try to get rid of ~ in your path.

But also, you can check out [this guide](http://www.robgreen.me/post/Useful-C-Image-Upload-Example.aspx)